# Error while creating a loopback application in strongloop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have installed all the dependency for strongloop, e.g nodejs v0.12.0 and npm 2.5.1, and of course the strongloop using:

```
npm install strongloop
```

as its mentioned in their getting started page,and I can see the node_modules have been created for the strongloop however when I try to create a loopback application by using:

```
slc loopback
```

I keep getting this error:

Error loading module "loopback":
 [Error: Module did not self-register.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I have to add the -g flag during installation, I have been looking inside the docs about if it has a special meaning, I guess its used for global installation which I am kinda not a fan of! however it worked afterwards

Comment: Strongloop is not really part of your app, it's the framework. So it's meant to be installed per environment. Installing it globally puts slc and the other scripts in your path so you can use them on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Install strongloop globally using command:
`npm install -g strongloop`

Then use:
`slc loopback`

If you still get the error then go to:

> C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming

and delete the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders then re-install the strongloop.